# Special characters in Python string replace

Tags: python

I have a string in `python` I want to replace any special characters in that string.

I have done like below

```
col_name = 'AN*_Gen_**Air_&Outlet_$Temp'

reps = (('_&', ' '), ('*_', '('), ('_*', ')'), ('#_', '{'), ('_#', '}'), ('_##', ';'), ('_$', '.'),
        ('_$$', ','), ('_**', '='))

original_cols = reduce(lambda a, kv: a.replace(*kv), reps, col_name)
```

Output:

```
'AN(Gen)*Air Outlet.Temp'
```

Expected output:

```
'AN(Gen=Air Outlet.Temp'
```

Here I see that in the string `_**` is being first replaced by `)*` instead of `=` as `_*` in `reps` is `)`

What should I do to get the correct string?

Comment: Put `_**` before `_*`?

Comment: and similarly for `_#` and `_$`

Comment: @internet_user Your solution works for me but Is there a way I can avoid `Put _** before _*`

Comment: You can also use regex to make it one-pass. In current solution the string is scanned many times.

Comment: What output do you expect when there are different possibilities? Why is  `=` more correct than `)*` in your case? What should happen with `_#_`, `#_#`, `#_*_#`, `_##_`, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `('_**', '=')` before `('*_', '(')` as more characters match should be higher preference.

```
reps = (('_**', '='), ('_&', ' '), ('*_', '('), ('_*', ')'), ('#_', '{'), ('_#', '}'), ('_##', ';'), ('_$', '.'),
        ('_$$', ','))
```

Output

```
'AN(Gen=Air Outlet.Temp'
```

Comment: Your solution works for me but Is there a way I can avoid  it.  I want to do this without worrying about the placement of the reps

Comment: [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) is helpful too